# Boost installer confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost

I just downloaded and ran the [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) installer (the one called "BoostPro 1.42.0 Installer" [here](http://www.boostpro.com/download)). I then looked in `c:\program files\boost\boost_1_42` to check everything was installed correctly, only to find a collection of zip files and nothing else. Did I do something wrong? I was hoping to see a collection of .lib files. There is a "lib" directory, but when I open that I just see a large collection of .zip files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved... it appears that the installation was simply not completed, it had stalled half way through with an error message, but the window telling me this was not topmost and I missed it.